# Searching for ID from big lists faster in python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

So I have these two lists:

```
image_names = ["IMG_1.jpg", "IMG_2.jpg"]
data = [{"name": "IMG_1.jpg", "id": "53567"},
        {"name": "IMG_2.jpg", "id": "53568"},
        {"name": "IMG_3.jpg", "id": "53569"},
        {"name": "IMG_4.jpg", "id": "53570"}]
```

I want to search for the first item then the next one and so on in images_names in data and if it has the same name to get the id and add it to a list.

This is how I'm doing this:

```
for image_name in image_names:
    for datum in data:
        datum_name = datum.get("name", None)
        if datum_name == image_name:
           images_ids.append(datum.get("id", None))
```

Right now it works great but I think this is really inefficient once I get a lot of data in images_names and data. What's the best way in Python to do this? I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that your data structure isn't set up to give you the access you want.  Instead of a list of dicts, make this the natural dict that you want to use:

```
data = {"IMG_1.jpg": "53567",
        "IMG_2.jpg": "53568",
        "IMG_3.jpg": "53569",
        "IMG_4.jpg": "53570"}
```

Now, all you need to make the list of corresponding `id`s is

```
images_ids = [data[img] for img in image_names]
```

If you have a need for both methods of access (if you still need the `name` and `id` labels), then I recommend that you learn to use a Pandas data frame, with `name` and `id` as the columns.  This will give you the best of both methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> images_ids = [filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, data) for name in image_names]
>>> images_ids = [i[0]['id'] for i in images_ids if i]
>>> images_ids
['53567', '53568']
```

Answer (score 2):

Other option:

```
[ item["id"] for item in data if item["name"] in image_names]
#=> ['53567', '53568']
```

It works also when **images with same name exist with different ids**:

```
data = [{"name": "IMG_1.jpg", "id": "53500"},{"name": "IMG_1.jpg", "id": "53501"}]
#=> ['53500', '53501']
```

Comment: Best answer! Great thinking!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is inefficient. Instead of using a list of dictionaries, you should use either a dictionary of dictionaries or a dictionary of objects:

```
data = {"IMG_1.jpg": {"id": "53567"},
    "IMG_2.jpg": {"id": "53568"},
    "IMG_3.jpg": {"id": "53569"},
    "IMG_4.jpg": {"id": "53570"}}

for image_name in image_names:
    if (image_name in data):
        image_ids.append(data[image_name]["id"])
```

Instead of O(n) for lookup in a list, you'll get O(1) for lookup in a dictionary.

Of course, you can still have `name` as a key in your sub-dictionary if you want, I just removed it for simplicity. But the real holy grail here would be to build a class:

```
class ImageData:

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.Name = name
        self.Id = id

data = {"IMG_1.jpg": ImageData("IMG_1.jpg", "53567"),
    "IMG_2.jpg": ImageData("IMG_2.jpg", "53568"),
    "IMG_3.jpg": ImageData("IMG_3.jpg", "53569"),
    "IMG_4.jpg": ImageData("IMG_4.jpg", "53570")}

for image_name in image_names:
    if (image_name in data):
        image_ids.append(data[image_name].Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and filter, you can try this out. This works with your existing data, though I would highly recommend you restructure your dictionary as per recommendation of others-

```
images_ids = [datum.get("id", None) for datum in data for image_name in 
image_names if datum.get("name", None) == image_name ]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for 2 loops here. You can iterate the first loop and search for Image Name in second list, If matches add the id to the Image Ids. Like below

```
    for datum in data:
          datum_name = datum.get("name", None)
          if any(datum_name in s for s in image_names):
                 images_ids.append(datum.get("id", None))
```